# Non replicable SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am experiencing a weird case of the SettingWithCopyWarning not behaving as I would expect it to behave.

I have a dataframe with lots of columns and over 100000 rows of Facebook data of posts published by a public page. The five columns that I am interested in are 'Page Name', 'Created', 'Message', 'Image Text','Link Text', and 'Description'.

First, I extract the columns I need using the following two lines of code (let's call this lines 1 and 2):

```
reqd_cols = ['Page Name', 'Created', 'Message', 'Link Text', 'Image Text', 'Description']
reqd_dat = raw_dat[reqd_cols]
```

The `Created` column has the timestamp (`str`) of when the post was created (for e.g. `2021-02-08 20:06:19 EST`). My goal is to extract the Date from this column and store it in a new column called "Date"

I am able to extract the Date and create a list using

```
reqd_dat.loc[:,'Created'].str.split().str[0].tolist()
```

However, when I do (line 3)

```
reqd_dat.loc[:,'Date'] = reqd_dat.loc[:,'Created'].str.split().str[0].tolist()
```

I get the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning`. However, after getting the warning, when I rerun  lines 1 and 2, thereby effectively recreating `reqd_dat`, line 3 no longer throws that warning.

What am I missing?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe system is smart and it remember that it already displayed this error and it skip it. Frankly, why bother this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `reqd_dat` is a view of `raw_dat`. I would try changing line 2 to:

```
reqd_dat = raw_dat[reqd_cols].copy()
```